# Why is my nestjs-based server using Passport always returning 401 for my endpoints, even when a valid JWT Token is present?

Tags: typescript, authentication, passport.js, nestjs

You aren't going to believe this, but I'm building an API for a Todo server!  Yay!

I'm using Nestjs, Auth0, and Passport to do my authentication.  I have verified that the client is sending a valid token.

I'm also pulling my hair out because I can't seem to get the `/todo` controller to ever return anything but a 401 error.

I have done my due diligence on Google, but alas, nothing seems to work.

So, here's my JWT Strategy:

```
import { passportJwtSecret } from 'jwks-rsa';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy, VerifiedCallback } from 'passport-jwt';

import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      //jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt'),
      audience: 'http://localhost:3000',
      issuer: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/`,
    });
  }

  validate(payload: any, done: VerifiedCallback) {
    if (!payload) {
      console.log('DENIED!!!!!');
      done(new UnauthorizedException(), false); // 2
    }

    return done(null, payload);
  }
}
```

Here is my todo controller:

```
import { ValidationPipe } from './../utils/validation.pipe';
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Param,
  Body,
  Post,
  Put,
  Delete,
  Query,
  ParseBoolPipe,
  UsePipes,
  UseGuards,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ToDosService } from './to-dos.service';
import { classToPlain } from 'class-transformer';
import { Todo } from '../models/todo.model';
import { ObjectID } from 'typeorm';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller('todos')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))  
export class ToDosController {
  constructor(private todosService: ToDosService) {}

  @Get()
  async getAllTodos() {
    const todosEntities = await this.todosService.getAllTodos();
    const todos = classToPlain(todosEntities);
    return todos;
  }

  @Get('complete')
  async getTodos(@Query('iscomplete', new ParseBoolPipe()) isComplete) {
    let todosEntities: Todo[];

    if (isComplete) {
      todosEntities = await this.todosService.getCompletedTodos();
    } else {
      todosEntities = await this.todosService.getIncompleteTodos();
    }
    const todos = classToPlain(todosEntities);
    return todos;
  }

  @Get(':id')
  async getTodo(@Param('id') id: ObjectID): Promise<Todo> {
    return this.todosService.getTodo(id);
  }

  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
  @Post()
  async createTodo(@Body() todo: Todo) {
    return this.todosService.createTodo(todo);
  }

  @Put(':id')
  async updTodo(@Param('id') id: ObjectID, @Body() todo: Todo) {
    return this.todosService.updateTodo(id, todo);
  }

  @Delete(':id')
  async deleteTodo(@Param('id') id: ObjectID) {
    return this.todosService.deleteTodo(id);
  }
}
```

If you are so inclined, a complete look at the project can be found here:

https://github.com/NickHodges/nestjstodoserver

The call to `http:/localhost:3000/todos` returns 401 no matter what I try.

Any ideas from anyone?

Comment: Nick, I’m curious. What is the purpose of the @function names. Never seen that before, in fact I don’t think I’ve ever seen an @ used in JavaScript before. Can you explain?

Comment: Wait, so you commented out the guard and you're _still_ getting a 401?

Comment: @zipzit The `@` before a method in Typescript makes the method a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). These allow you to set metadata without having to get too into the weeds on how that metadata is actually used. Decorators are a big point in both [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com) and [Angular](https://angular.io/docs) ad while they are still only [a stage 2 proposa](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html), they probably will not be going away.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel -- no, sorry.  I'll fix that up -- turns out a validation middleware gumming up the works.  I removed it, and now it give me a 401 whenever I use `UseGuard` and returns the data when I don't.

Comment: How did you solve it? Can you please share the details as answer? I am struggling with something similar.